# try{...}catch does not throw exception in PHP/Symfony2/PHPImap

Tags: php, symfony, exception, try-catch

I am using the [ImapMail](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) Library and try to initiate a new Mailbox:

```
    try{
        $mailbox = new ImapMailbox($url, $username, $password);
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return new Response("fail");
    }
```

But the above try/catch does not work, although symfony gives me this:

```
Connection error: (is empty) 
 500 Internal Server Error - Exception
```

the Stacktrace

```
 in vendor/php-imap/php-imap/src/PhpImap/Mailbox.php at line 67:

    protected function initImapStream() {
        $imapStream = @imap_open($this->imapPath, $this->imapLogin, $this->imapPassword, $this->imapOptions, $this->imapRetriesNum, $this->imapParams);
        if(!$imapStream) {
            throw new Exception('Connection error: ' . imap_last_error());
        }
        return $imapStream;
    }
```

([Direct link to function on github](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap/blob/master/src/PhpImap/Mailbox.php#L64))

It does throw a new Exception, why can't I catch it?

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: typo in `catch (\Exception $e)` ?? was it meant to be `catch (Exception $e)`

Comment: Well, I use the global namespace Exception, but even if I don't no catch...

Comment: Is this the entire code or do you have other catch blocks on the same level? Perhaps the error is caught by another catch block?

Comment: No, here is the whole code: http://pastebin.com/GMTXyAwm. The class is on github (link above)

Comment: have you added the `use` statement for the `Response` object?

Comment: Also, are you sure this is the code causing the problem? If you remove the  call to `new ImapMailbox()` do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Whole Controller: http://pastebin.com/5PaP9jt5 @Carlos Granados: I don't and I know it's coming from the Mailbox Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very simple. You call only class constructor in try block. If you look into the class source code, you will see that constructor does call nothing.

https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap/blob/master/src/PhpImap/Mailbox.php#L20-L31

It means code throwing exception must be under you try/catch. You have to move it inside try block if you want to catch the exception. I am talking about `$mailbox->checkMailbox()`. This command throws exception.

Comment: PERFECT, I tried it with the whole IF Statement of checkMailbox(), no result. Now I know why...